# Query to fetch records which are updated within last 60 mintues

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

My Sample Table looks like this ..

```
Primary_Key  || Start_Time || End_Time || Value

1 || 24-FEB-13 18:00:00 || 24-FEB-13 19:00:00 || 6
```

The data types of these columns are

```
Primary_Key --   Int  
Start_Time  ---  TimeStamp  
End_Time    ---  TimeStamp  
Value       ---  Int
```

Now , i want to fetch all the records in the table which have the End_Time value within the 60 mins of the current time ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable
WHERE end_time >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - NUMToDSInterval(1, 'HOUR')
```

That should work with DATE and TIMESTAMP and TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE values.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select *
from sample s
where CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - end_time <= 1/24.0 and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP >= end_time
```

Comment: this error is throwing up ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND got NUMBER

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select * from yourtable
WHERE (sysdate - End_Time) * 1440 between 0 and 60
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this - select your data between your_start_date and your_start_date + INTERVAL '60' MINUTE:

```
SELECT SYSDATE start_dt, (SYSDATE + INTERVAL '60' MINUTE) end_dt 
  FROM dual
/

SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT  to_date('24-FEB-13 18:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') your_start_date
       ,(to_date('24-FEB-13 18:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') + INTERVAL '60' MINUTE) your_end_dt 
 FROM dual
)
/
```